# numpy matrix from arrays - python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, matrix

i have created matrix with 4 main informations about the nodes of a graph that i want to manipulate and i'm trying to save them as an array of arrays.
and with an associative array ordered to iterate on a certain information

this is the matrix with my informations

```
nodes = [[0 for x in range(4)] for y in range(n)]
for i in range(nodeNumber+1):
    nodes[i] = info1[i], info2[i] , info[3] , i
```

How do i create the same matrix with numpy?

i've tried to create a matrix from my 'nodes' but it's like i've an array of tuples and not a matrix, as numpy does not see it as one

Answer (score 0):

```
In [114]: n=3
In [115]: nodes = [[0 for x in range(4)] for y in range(n)]
In [116]: nodes
Out[116]: [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

So you have created a list, which contains lists

```
In [117]: for i in range(3):
     ...:     nodes[i] = 1,2,3,i
     ...:     
In [118]: nodes
Out[118]: [(1, 2, 3, 0), (1, 2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3, 2)]
```

Now you have replaced each element of `nodes` list with a tuple `(1,2,3,1)`.  The is a complete replacement.  It does not modify the sublists of `nodes`.  So now `nodes` is a list of tuples.

```
In [119]: np.array(nodes)
Out[119]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [1, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 2]])
```

Passing that through `np.array` creates a 2d array, regardless of whether it is a list of lists or list of tuples.

If the sublists or tuples differ in length you'll get something else - a 1d array of dtype object.

You'll have to be more specific as to what you mean by `array of arrays` and `associative array`.